# Core-Plot: changing x axis labels (ie. instead of 12, 24, 26 be 1 year, 2 year, etc.)

Tags: graph, label, core-plot

My Core-Plot project incorporates ages on the X axis so the index is displayed in intervals of 12, which works find for months, but I want to show years instead. A previous project displays dates here, so I was hoping to use a similar function but so far have been unable.

Can anyone point me in a direction to display a custom x axis interval label so I can modify my index from 12, 24, 36 to 1 year, 2 year, 3 year (like the title)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set up an `NSNumberFormatter` to format the labels the way you want and tell the axis to use it to format the labels. Something like this:

```
NSNumberFormatter *newFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
newFormatter.minimumIntegerDigits = 1;
newFormatter.setPositiveSuffix = @" year";
xAxis.labelFormatter = newFormatter;
[newFormatter release];
```

Comment: NSNumberFormatter worked. I set the multiplier property to drop the numbers appropriately. Thanks!